# How to handle multiple tabs in cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, integration-testing

Im coding integration tests in a project with cypress. This is the flow in my projet:

- You click at a buy button of a projeto;
- When you click, open a new tab in checkout product

Only this, click at a button and open a new tab with the checkout screen. But as we know, cypress dont have suport for multiple tabs, so how can i handle it? What is the way to open  this new url in the same tab?

Important to highlight that this button is not wrapped by any `a` tag, its just a button that when I click has a `handleClick` that open a new tab and do other stuff. Because of this, none of these https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links/cypress/integration/tab_handling_anchor_links_spec.js solutions work for me.

I already tried this:

```
      cy.stub(win, "open")
        .callsFake((url, target) => {
          //@ts-ignore
          return win.open.wrappedMethod.call(win, url, "_self");
          //@ts-ignore
        })
        .as("open");
    });
```

but no success.

Comment: have you tried `.invoke()` method to remove attribute? If not. please use like `cy.get('.example > a').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()` . It will not open new tab but visite that url in same tab.